# hide a textbox if mouseleave beyond a certain time in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to hide a textbox only if the user hovers out > 2 seconds.

```
<div id="content">
 <input type="text" id="txt1" />
</div>


$('#content').on('mouseleave', function(){
   $('#txt1').delay(2000).hide();    
});
```

This will wait for 2 seconds before hiding the textbox. But if the user comes back within 2 seconds it will still hide. How to prevent that from happening?

Comment: In your example when user leaves the input then it will hide after 2 seconds. Is that you want?

Comment: If the user comes back within the 2 seconds, then it should not hide.

Comment: Attention everyone, there are 5 answers using `setTimeout` already; please stop answering this with `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTimeout/clearTimeout` instead:

```
var clr;
$('#content').on('mouseleave', function () {
    clr = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#txt1').hide();
    }, 2000)
}).on('mouseenter', function () {
    clearTimeout(clr)
})
```

Also note that the delay in your example won't work at all since the .delay() method delays the execution of functions that follow it in the standard effects queue or with a custom queue. It won't delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use the effects queue.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UDL7X/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the good ol' fashion [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) and [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearTimeout)

```
var leaveTimeout;
$('#content').on('mouseleave', function() {
   leaveTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      $('#txt1').hide();
   }, 2000);   
})
.on('mouseenter', function() {
   clearTimeout(leaveTimeout);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a simpler CSS solution: http://jsfiddle.net/2Jtrb/2/.

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <input type="text" id="txt1" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    outline: 1px dotted #000;
}

div > input {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 2s;
    transition: visibility 2s;
}
```

EDIT: the input will also stay visible if it is focused.

```
div:hover > input, input:focus {
    visibility: visible;
    transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var theTimer;

$('#content').on('mouseleave', function(){
    theTimer =  setTimeout(function() {
       $('#txt1').hide();    
    }, 2000);
});

$('#content').on('mouseenter', function(){
    clearTimeout(theTimer); 
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cyY6E/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `setTimeout` you can cancel the timeout if the user enters the text area again. That code looks something like:

```
var timeoutHandle;
$('#content').on('mouseleave', function(){
   timeoutHandle = setTimout(
      function () {
        timeoutHandle = undefined;
        $('#txt1').hide();
      }, 2000);
});

$('#content').on('mouseenter', function(){
   if (timeoutHandle) clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
});
```

By the way, this is similar to what other plugins provide so you might consider looking at the hover intent plugin here: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
var typingTimer;
$('#content').on('mouseleave', function(){
typingTimer = setTimeout(function(){
$('#txt1').hide();  
},2000);
});
$('#content').on('mouseenter', function(){
clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout function.

```
var timeout = null; 
$('#content').on('mouseleave', function() { 
    timeout = setTimeout(function() { $('#text1').hide();
});
```

Then when the user enters the div, clear the timeout.

```
$('#content').on('mouseenter', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```

I wrote this without looking anything up, so I hope I didn't messed up ;)